# RealTime with pusher-js & nextjs?

Tags: next.js, real-time, pusher-js

I found Pusher-js docs is not very usefull to get start with, Is there any tutorial I can follow to learn exactly how the flow will look like?

Answer (score 1):

The front end javascript will be the same: https://pusher.com/docs/channels/getting_started/javascript/ . If you're using Vercel, you can use their serverless functions for backend message triggering. I got it working with Python. Follow their instructions on how to add the Pusher server library https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/supported-languages